# View feedback onTouch

Tags: android, android-layout, touch, ripple

I want my views to be able to give feedback on touch and so I do

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />
```

However, I don't see any feedback when I touch my views.

For my specific case I have a RecyclerView with items, and I want the view of each item to give feedback. And so in the `.xml` of the item, I placed the background as `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"`. Is there more to it?

Comment: view.setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

Comment: @dex thanks, I see what I was doing wrong. Do you know by any chance how to change the dull gray to something of my choosing (in xml).

Comment: You need to write your own selector and then set it to background. some thing like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>

Comment: I did that and set clickable to true but it didn't work. But this seems a whole thing by itself so I will ask a new question and tag here. Thanks.

Comment: I re-ask the question so as not to be rude. Sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33246793/add-custom-color-to-touch-feedback-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

View have to be clickable so add android:clickable="true". This is auto added when you set onClickListener.

If this doesn't help it would be nice to share your .xml resource file. It depends on what kind of states have to specified in it.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html

Edit based on comments:

Api <= 19:

```
<selector xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    a:drawable="@color/gray230"
    a:state_pressed="true" />

</selector>
```

Api > 19 (touch feedback limited to view bounds)

```
<ripple xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:color="@color/gray230">

<item
    a:id="@android:id/mask"
    a:drawable="@android:color/black" />

<item>

    <selector>

        <item
            a:drawable="@color/gray230"
            a:state_selected="true"/>

    </selector>

</item>

</ripple>
```

Api > 19 (without view bounds limit)

```
<ripple xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
a:color="@color/gray230">
</ripple>
```

This is what I'm using. Usually I'm setting these resource files as background resource. This, of course, can be done with code as well.

Comment: Thanks. I was setting the background on the card. Thanks. So how do I change the gray to something nicer, do you know?

Comment: I have written it once. It is different on API <= 19 and after than. Now it is late at night at the place where I am, but tomorrow I will check it and write down the entire .xml file