# Add custom color to touch feedback in android

Tags: android, android-layout, touch

To give users visual feedback when they touch a view, I do

```
<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />
```

But `?attr/selectableItemBackground` is a gray color. I want to use a different color. To do *that* I do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">;
    <item android:drawable="@color/mine" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@color/mine" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
</selector>
```

but it does not work, even after I set `clickable="true"` for the view in question.

Comment: did you change `?attr/selectableItemBackground` with your `drawable`?

Comment: :) yes I did, @Blackbelt. I double checked.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the code

button_normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:shape="rectangle">

   <solid android:color="@color/button_light_green"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

button_selected.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:shape="rectangle">

   <solid android:color="@color/button_light_green_selected"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```

button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/> 
</selector>
```

assign button_background.xml as background for the button by changing the colors which u desire. Hope it works!!!